# I have to create a two methods one for a clockwise rotation and the other anticlockwise

Tags: java, math, transformation

I have two methods one to take points that the user enters then perform a calculation to rotate is 90 degrees clockwise while in the other method, its the exact same only 90 degrees anticlockwise. I have tried it but i`m getting the wrong results, any suggestion on ways to fix it,

```
private static String Clockwise(int Amount, int[] x, int[] y) {
        String message = "";
        int[] tempX = x;
        int[] tempY = y;

        for (int count = 0; count <= Amount; count++) {//amount of times
            message = "\n";
            for (int index = 0; index < pointer; index++) {//go through array
                tempX[index] = tempX[index] * -1;//multiply X
                tempY[index] = tempY[index] * 1;//multiply Y

                message += ("(" + y[index] + "," + x[index] + ")\n");//output
            }//end for  
        }//end outerfor
        return message;
    }//end clockwise

    private static String AntiClockwise(int Amount, int[] x, int[] y) {
        String message = "";
        int[] tempX = x;
        int[] tempY = y;
        for (int count = 0; count <= Amount; count++) {//amount of times
            message = "\n";
            for (int index = 0; index < pointer; index++) {//go through for loop
                tempX[index] = tempX[index] * 1;//multiply X
                tempY[index] = tempY[index] * -1;//multiply Y
                message += ("(" + tempY[index] + "," + tempX[index] + ")\n");//create message
            }//end for  
        }//end outerfor

        return message;
    }//end anticlockwise
```

Comment: What results do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: The problem is that you are mirroring about one axis on each step - to rotate by 90 degrees, the X coordinate comes from the Y coordinate, and the Y coordinate comes from the X coordinate.

Comment: Provide sample inputs with expected and actual results. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would help.

Comment: As addition to @AndyTurner 's comment: `tempX[index] = tempYindex] * -1;
                tempY[index] = tempX[index] * 1;` (might turn anticlock-wise, depending on what x and y is in your context).

Comment: The Y value is supposed to be negative once multiplied by -1 @Thomas

Comment: So the original X and Y values are (5,4) and the answer I get is (4,5) and I get the same result for anticlockwise as well @erickson

Comment: Note that there is no advantage to the `tempX` and `tempY` variables - you aren't copying the array when you write `int[] tempX = x;`. You may as well just use the original variables.

Comment: Also, note that the for loop should use `count < Amount`, not `<=`: if `Amount == 0`, you shouldn't rotate once.

Comment: @AndyTurner in the switch statement for the menu it ensures that the amount has to be greater than 0

Comment: OK - but if you enter 1 you don't want to rotate it twice. It currently rotates it one step too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate anti-clockwise by a general angle around the origin, the formula is:

```
x_new =  cos(theta)*x - sin(theta)*y
y_new =  sin(theta)*x + cos(theta)*y
```

So, if you want to rotate by some multiple of 90 degrees, you can simply use:

```
double theta = Math.toRadians(90 * N);
```

and substitute that into the formula. This means that you don't need a loop to rotate N times - just rotate once by the actual angle.

---

However, if you want to do it by 90 degrees on each rotation, you can simply substitute in the values of cos(90 deg) and sin(90 deg) (to do an anticlockwise rotation):

```
x_new = cos(90 deg)*x - sin(90 deg)*y = 0*x - 1*y = -y
y_new = sin(90 deg)*x + cos(90 deg)*y = 1*x + 0*y =  x
```

Hence:

```
x_new = -y
y_new = x
```

There is advantage in doing it this way, since a couple of assignments like this are a lot faster than doing the full math.

Note that you have to be careful not to write:

```
x = -y;
y = x;
```

because the second of these statements uses the result of the first. You need to store the original `x` in a temporary variable to do this correctly.